# Is it possible to replace sub object with other object in main object?

Tags: javascript

I want to replace the sub object with some other object in main object.

ex:

```
var mianobj = {"a":{"aa":{"aaa":"0000","bbb":"1111"}},"b":"222","c":"333"}
var newsubobj = {"n":"8888","g":"9999"}

console.log(mainobj.a.aa)
// this gives the sub object --> {"aaa":"0000","bbb":"1111"}
```

I want to replace this object with `newsubobj`.

I need the result as ::

```
console.log(mainobj); 
// {"a":{"aa":{"n":"8888","g":"9999"}},"b":"222","c":"333"}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: doesn't `mainobj.a.aa = newsubobj;` work?

Comment: have you tried `mainobj.a.aa = newsubobj`?

Comment: also, your first `mainobj` has a typo...

Comment: @user579452: So, do it! Have you heard of the `=` operator?

Answer (score 4):

Why you don't do it like that:
`mainobj.a.aa = newsubobj`
?

Comment: @jswolf19 Its working fine in console. Not in dynamicalyy. Actually my mainobj is global object, i am getting the sub obj path like var subobjpath = a.aa , if i assign mainobj.subobjpath = newsubobj // at this case newsubobj is created with parllel to mainobj

Answer (score 1):

Ah, now we're getting somewhere. To update your question you have:

```
var mainobj = {"a":{"aa":{"aaa":"0000","bbb":"1111"}},"b":"222","c":"333"}
var subobjpath = "a.aa"; // this needs to be a string
var newsubobj = {"n":"8888","g":"9999"}
```

and you want to use `subobjpath` to replace a part of `mainobj` with `newsubobj`.

You can do so using code like this:

```
var path = subobjpath.split('.');
var obj = mainobj;
for(var idx=0; idx < path.length-1;idx++) obj = mainobj[path[idx]];
obj[path[path.length-1]] = newsubobj;
```

Comment: @Nagendra, Just be careful if you have strangely named members that include the '.' character ^_^

Comment: @Nagendra: If its working fine.. why can't you accept this answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
var mainobj = {"a":{"aa":{"aaa":"0000","bbb":"1111"}},"b":"222","c":"333"};

var newsubobj = {"n":"8888","g":"9999"};

mainobj.a.aa = newsubobj;

console.log(mainobj);
```

Comment: Actually my mainobj is global object, i am getting the sub obj path like var subobjpath = a.aa , if i assign mainobj.subobjpath = newsubobj // at this case newsubobj is created with parllel to mainobj.

Comment: @user579542 i think subobjpath is being replace by newsubobject rather than being created

Comment: @experimentX Its not replacing, it is appending at the top.

Comment: @user579542 appending at the top (prepending) should display the original values of mainobj.a.aa, but it does not. something like mainobj.a.abc = newsubobj would;